# how to get refresh token in Sign In with Google for Web

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, google-oauth, google-signin

i was trying to migrate from old google login library to new gis library, during the process i was not able to implement refresh token logic. my app gets logout every hour the token gets expire and user have to login again. which is not good for my customer experience. please help

i tried using Javascript api  code from the official website [[https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference]](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference)

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
      callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to ask for the `offline` scope when calling Google's authorization endpoint. Offline access is Google's way of saying that you want the refresh token.

Comment: client side JavaScript does not support refresh tokens.  Use a server sided language instead.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo old sign in with google never ends session until user logs out by themself. is this feature not available in new sign in with google
old library - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
new library - https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Comment: The new library splits Oauth2 and Sign-in refresh tokens are restricted to server sided Oauth2.   Client side sign-in require that a user sign in again if the session has expired.  Which happens automatically after an hour

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo if you have only one active session it automatically sign us in but if u have multiple session / user logged then we have to select user again again the prompt.